# How to format a csv file so that R can read it correctly

Tags: r, csv

So I have a csv file that is being created on-the-fly by some java-based code (processing).  The problem is when I try to load it in R it adds a column at the start for what seems to be no reason, and then leaves one column in the middle filled with NA's.

Here is what the csv file looks like.

```
 x1,x2,y1,y2,angle,size1,size2,distance1,distance2
 400.0,1100.0,500.0,500.0,0.0,,0.0,0.0,-100.0,600.0
```

Now the thing is, I tried to open it in open office just for giggles and It opened just fine.
[image]

Now in R using read.csv() it opens it like this: [image]

So I figured the best place to start with my investigation is where the file is being created itself.

Here is the processing code:

```java
out.println("x1,"+ "x2," + "y1," + "y2," + "angle," + "size1," + "size2," + "distance1," + "distance2");
for (int i = 0; i < directions; i++)
{
  //extraneous code skipped
  String output =  pointX + "," +  point2X + "," +  pointY + "," + point2Y + "," + (double)angle + "," +  "," + size1 + "," + size2 + "," +  distance + "," + distance2;
  out.println(output);
}
```

Anyway, I could use some hints as to what is wrong or work around suggestions.

Comment: 9 headers, 10 fields, there's 2 continuous comma, seems r guess consider the headers are for the last columns where openoffice discard the double separator.  Seems coming from `+ (double)angle + "," +  "," + size1` this part

Comment: Try adding `row.names=False` to your `read.csv()` call to prevent `R` from using the first column as row names. Regarding the `NA`s I guess they are due to the `,,` in your `CSV`. This basically says, there is an entry but its empty. Since `R` doesn't know what type it is setting `col.classes` might help.

Comment: Just noticed that `read.csv` doesn't support the option I mentioned. Either witch to the more general `read.table` or adjust your input as @Tensibai explained. Removing the 2nd `,` will immediately fix your problem.

Comment: Please post the `read.csv` call. There are various parameters that affect how it loads CSV files, esp. regarding guessing of column types and handling of missing values as in your case (angle). As a rule though, you should *avoid* creating files with missing values. CSV is *not* a well-defined format and the interpretation of missing values is up to the reader. In this case, `N/A` makes more sense than 0

Comment: I was just doing the vanilla call no optional parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already explained in the comments, you input has a double comma (`,,`):

```sh
cat 'wrong.csv'
```

```
x1,x2,y1,y2,angle,size1,size2,distance1,distance2
 400.0,1100.0,500.0,500.0,0.0,,0.0,0.0,-100.0,600.0
```

Removing that will fix the problem:

```sh
cat 'right.csv'
```

```
x1,x2,y1,y2,angle,size1,size2,distance1,distance2
 400.0,1100.0,500.0,500.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,-100.0,600.0
```

Here you can see the difference:

```sh
Rscript -e 'read.csv("wrong.csv");read.csv("right.csv")'
```

```
        x1  x2  y1 y2 angle size1 size2 distance1 distance2
400.0 1100 500 500  0    NA     0     0      -100       600
   x1   x2  y1  y2 angle size1 size2 distance1 distance2
1 400 1100 500 500     0     0     0      -100       600
```

The reason is that `R` treats `,,` as a column without value. Since it's not clear that this is a `character`, it is not interpreted as empty string (`""`) but as missing value (`NA`).
Since this way your input has one more data column than headers, `read.csv` interprets the first column as row names for the resulting `data.frame`.
Thus, you do not get an error but the unexpected output.
By fixing the column number, the `R` understands that column 1 is actually `x1` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

If we count the fields we see that there are 9 header columns but 10 data columns so it assumes the extra data column is the first and that first column represents the row names.

```
count.fields(textConnection(Lines), sep = ",")
[1]  9 10
```

To address this skip the header and read the data in removing the extra column 6.  Then read in the header line and apply the headers to the data frame.

```
# test data
Lines <- "x1,x2,y1,y2,angle,size1,size2,distance1,distance2
 400.0,1100.0,500.0,500.0,0.0,,0.0,0.0,-100.0,600.0"


DF <- read.table(text = Lines, skip = 1, sep = ",")[-6]
names(DF) <- unlist(read.table(text = Lines, nrows = 1, sep = ","))
```

We have used `text = Lines` to keep this self contained but, of course, you would instead use something like `file = "myfile.csv"` instead.